# Rails combine two different active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables residing in two different databases.

Example:

Users residing in **db1** with attributes **user_id and name**

Audit residing in **db2** with attributes **id and user_id**

```
User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users")

Audit.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM audits")
```

How do I combine result of these two query results based on user_id

Expected Output rows => **user_id audit_id name**

Comment: did you manage to get results from two different databases? it's then simply a manner of plucking together a result object

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this in ruby you could just use mapping

```
users = User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users")

audits = Audit.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM audits")

result = []
users.each do |u|
   result << { 
     user_id: u.id,
     name: u.name,
     audits: audits.find_all { |a| a.user_id == u.id } 
   }
end

result

# result will include all user audits
```

in map you may build your hash with whatever you like

Comment: In here, users variable get filled up with audits. Can you suggest how to have/map both users and audit into users  ?

Comment: @SitharaSuresh see updated code in answer, that may be what you are looking for, if you want it to be exactly as you pointed out you then will have to do double (nested) iteration